# Insert string in a Binary tree

Tags: java, insert, binary-tree

I am trying to create a binary tree that takes strings but it uses "-" and "+" to go left or right if the sign is + insert left and if it's - then insert right. Here is a visual representation of what I am trying to do.

[image]

insert method should take the word and just a single sign for now and based of that insert right or left

Here is my code but I am getting nullpointer error. Apparently, I am not inserting into the right order

```
public class BinaryTree {
    
    private static Node root = null;
    private static Node sign = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        BinaryTree bt = new BinaryTree();
        bt.insert("to", "-");
        bt.insert("the", "+");
        bt.preorder();

    }
    
    private class Node {
        String data;
        String sign;
        Node left;
        Node right;
        
    
    public Node(String w) {
        data = w;
        left = right = null;
        
    }
    
//  public Node(String w, String s) {
//      data = w;
//      sign = s;
//      left = right = null;
//      
//  }
    
    
    } // -----------------end of Node
    
    private void insert(String val, String sign) {
        root = insert(root, val, sign);
        
    }
    
    Node insert(Node r, String data, String passSign) {
        if (r == null) {
            return new Node(data);
        }
        
        if(r.sign.equals(passSign)) {
            r.right = insert(r.right, data, passSign);
        } 
        else if (r.sign.equals(passSign)){
            r.left = insert(r.left, data, passSign);
        }
        return r;
    }
    
    public void preorder() {
        preorder(root);
    }
    
    public void preorder(Node p) {
        if (p != null) {
            System.out.println(p.data);
            preorder(p.left);
            preorder(p.right);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `r.sign.equals(passSign)` does not correspond to the logic you have explained. Why should `sign` be a property of the tree or of a node? Also, any reason why you think the second time you evaluate this expression it will lead to a different result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problems are:

- The `BinaryTree` nor the `Node` instances should have a `sign` member. The sign only plays a role during the insertion process, but has no meaning any more once a node is inserted
- `r.sign.equals(passSign)` is therefore also not the correct condition to check. According to your description you should just check whether the sign is a "-" and go right, or else go left ("+"). There is no *state* of the node that influences this decision. So do `passSign.charAt(0) == '-'` instead.
- When making the recursive call you should not pass the same sign again: it has already been processed. Instead, pass any signs that *follow* after the consumed one. You can use `substring` for that purpose.
- The image shows a root node that has no value. Yet you are right in creating a tree instance with no node at all. So your `insert` method should deal with the case where the `root` is null, but the sign argument is not the empty string. In that case a `root` node should be created, but it should not hold the target data, as for that we should still go deeper in the tree. This principle could apply to any node, not only the root. So foresee the creation of such "place-holder" nodes and give them some default value (like "(null)").

Not a problem, but I find it more useful to print in `inorder` order, and indent the deeper nodes. This way you get an idea how the tree is structured.

Here is the corrected code:

```
public class BinaryTree {
    
    private static Node root = null;
    // No sign member needed;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinaryTree bt = new BinaryTree();
        bt.insert("to", "-");
        bt.insert("the", "+");
        bt.insert("buy", "-+");
        bt.insert("imperial", "+-");
        bt.insert("afflication", "++");
        bt.inorder();
    }
    
    private class Node {
        String data;
        // No sign member needed;
        Node left;
        Node right;
            
        public Node(String w) {
            data = w;
            left = right = null;    
        }
    }
    
    private void insert(String val, String sign) {
        root = insert(root, val, sign);
    }
    
    Node insert(Node r, String data, String passSign) {
        // Check whether there is a sign
        if (passSign.length() == 0) {
            return new Node(data);
        }
        // If needed, create a placeholder node so to be able to descend further
        if (r == null) {
            r = new Node("(null)");
        }
        
        if (passSign.charAt(0) == '-') {
            // Extract the rest of the signs
            r.right = insert(r.right, data, passSign.substring(1, passSign.length()));
        } 
        else {
            r.left = insert(r.left, data, passSign.substring(1, passSign.length()));
        }
        return r;
    }
    
    public void inorder() {
        inorder(root, "");
    }
    
    // This method gives a bit more visual output
    public void inorder(Node p, String indent) {
        if (p != null) {
            inorder(p.left, indent + "  ");
            System.out.println(indent + p.data);
            inorder(p.right, indent + "  ");
        }
    }
}
```